# Error: there were deployment errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2015

When I tried to run any sample application or a new one it shows this error. Can anyone help please?

[image]

Comment: screenshot is clearly showing the output window content.

Comment: Just clear the temporary files and restart the system. It will works.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The error is telling you that you have not selected a device:

**"Please select a valid device before running the application"**

You need to choice a physical phone (or Android emulator) to deploy the application to.

Ref: [Debug on Device](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-device/)

[image]

Comment: how to select emulator ? it is not showing me any window to select emulator.

Answer (score 1):

you have to have the android virtual device downloaded.

here are a few options:

- [Xamarin Android player](https://www.xamarin.com/android-player)
- [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)
- [Andy](http://www.andyroid.net/)
- [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)

Now that you have the virtual device. you need to start one before you run or debug.

The specific error you are seeing is because you've not started the device properly before you debug, you should be able to see the device.

Now run the project, and you wont meet this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Hyper V. 
Things you need to do are:

1.Turn off your Hyper V.(http://www.poweronplatforms.com/enable-disable-hyper-v-windows-10-8/)
2.Update your android SDK to desired platform.

 That set. Now run your app. It will work. 

Please let me know if still you have same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the Visual Studio Emulator for Android ([get it here](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdu6Hbw_jSAhVlAsAKHUpVDGsQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.visualstudio.com%2Fvs%2Fmsft-android-emulator%2F&usg=AFQjCNEhBdYEc7RbVhqKviAk428OfOh5Gw&sig2=RdIsOqSSH12mI-dY1aCmSw)), it plays very nice with Xamarin and Visual Studio and sets up your system automatically. As an added benefit it is very fast!