# XAMARIN Android builds solution but can't deploy vs2013

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I've just wrote a sample Xamarin Android App, everything builds correctly :

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App7, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
1>C:\Users\mepapasymeon\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\App7\App7\MainActivity.cs(14,13,14,18): warning CS0414: The field 'Phoneword.MainActivity.count' is assigned but its value is never used
1>  App7 -> C:\Users\mepapasymeon\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\App7\App7\bin\Debug\App7.dll
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
Build started.
Build succeeded.
Build started.
Build succeeded.
```

But when i press start

```
1>Please select a valid device before running the application.
1>------ Deploy started: Project: App7, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Error: Cancelled
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And this is the Xamarin Diagnostics :

```
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android SDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path does not contain adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\android-sdk-windows).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
    Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Android NDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack.exe in \. (C:\Users\mepapasymeon\Documents\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r10e).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory not found.
[I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 15, 19, 23
[I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 6.0.3
```

Comment: This question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647038/error-there-were-deployment-errors/36647624#36647624)

Comment: It works for me once cleared the temporary files and the system restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Error:

> 1>Please select a valid device before running the application.

---

You have to **install** and **configure** an emulator and then **select** a configured emulated phone that matches the API level (or above) that you are building your `.apk` for in order to "deploy" it. Or use a physical device that has been placed into **Developer Mode** with **USB Debugging Enabled** and connected to your Windows PC.

### Running the Visual Studio Android Emulator

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/

[image]

---

### Xamarin Android Player

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/xamarin-android-player/

Once the Xamarin Android Player is running, start Visual Studio and launch the Android ADB command prompt from the toolbar:

[image]

Inside the command prompt that appears, type in adb connect :

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647038/error-there-were-deployment-errors/36647624#36647624)

you have to have the android virtual device downloaded.

here are a few options:

- [Xamarin Android player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647038/error-there-were-deployment-errors/36647624#36647624)
- [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)
- [Andy](http://www.andyroid.net/)
- [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)

Now that you have the virtual device. you need to start one before you run or debug.

The specific error you are seeing is because you've not started the device properly before you debug, you should be able to see the device.

Now run the project, and you wont meet this error.